# How to set a text block of more than 3.9k characters based on a condition in a formula field?

Tags: formula-field, custom-metadata, long-text-area, quote-template, zuora

I have a requirement where I need to create a number of formula fields that will contain one or more paragraphs of legal verbiage based on certain conditions. But since formula fields only take 3.9k characters maximum, I'm not able to set the formula for one of the fields since the text block I'm trying to set exceeds 3.9k characters. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image: Can't set text block exceeding 3.9k characters]

I tried creating a custom metadata type object with the text block and referring to it in the above formula field but, alas, it also errors out since formula fields don't support long text areas. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image: Long text area custom metadata not allowed]

Is there an elegant solution to this or am I just wasting my time?

The only other solution that I can think of is having a normal long text area that will always contain the text block by default and having a formula for a checkbox with the required logic indicating if at all this text block should be used or not.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

**Note**: I'm trying to have these text blocks in a field in a particular object (Zuora Quote) so that after sync it will be available in Zuora and I'll be able to use the field in the Quote template to generate Quote PDFs.

Comment: This is your goal: _one or more paragraphs of legal verbiage based on certain conditions_ Why did you choose formula fields as your solution? One option: custom UI component such as LWC to render the text. To go further, consider how this text will be used in a higher-level business process. Perhaps an email template or another component that renders an order form would be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: Agreed if this is a UI concern, your focus on persisting to the database may be an unnecessary bottleneck.

Comment: @identigral I'm not sure if Zuora will be able to handle it. If I have the required verbiage in the Quote object then after Zuora sync it will be available in Zuora and I'll be able to use the field in the Quote template to generate Quote PDFs.

Comment: You could manage the text in Salesforce via a custom object or custom metadata and write it to Zuora via APIs. A simpler solution would be to break up the text to chunks of max characters, stick them on Zuora object in SF and glue them back together on Zuora end when rendering the quote.